# a2ensite error - site does not exist

Tags: apache2, websites

I would like to enable site in /etc/apache2/available-sites. Few hours ago everything was ok. Then I made some changes because of errors including copying directories in /etc/apache2 and now I can see directory with config files, but the files are empty a2ensite returns error site does not exist also ll command returns this result to console which I dont understand:

```
root@azure-camo-server:~# ll /etc/apache2/sites-available
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 19:50 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Jun  5 12:03 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Jun  5 12:01 .conf -> ../sites-available/.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Jun  5 12:01 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  582 Jun  5 12:21 camo.publicvm.com.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   49 Jun  5 12:01 kutkovak-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/kutkovak-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jun  5 12:01 kutkovak.conf -> ../sites-available/kutkovak.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun  5 19:50 tatrytec-eu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   52 Jun  5 12:01 tatrytec-eu-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/tatrytec-eu-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Jun  5 12:01 tatrytec-eu.conf -> ../sites-available/tatrytec-eu.conf
```

I dont understand what happens and how to fix it. Can somebody tell me please what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you copied `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, thereby destroying all your site configuration files and replacing them by symlinks pointing to themselves.

To fix this, restore the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory from the last good backup.

If you don't have a backup, you'll have to recreate all your site configuration files from scratch, memory or whatever information you may still have on what they contained.
Also take this as a hint to make regular backups in the future.

Comment: Does Apache backups of its directories himself? Or this is the worst scenario and I have no backup? I feel you will write no Apache does not backups of its directories by himself.

Comment: Luckily this is only test server...

Comment: One question. If I used cp to copy sites-available to sites-enabled what happened?

Comment: Sorry to confirm your fears, but no, Apache does not do backups.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you copy sites-available to sites-enabled on a normal working system then you have copies of all the configuration files in sites-enabled, instead of just symlinks for the enabled ones. If you'd do it now you'd just copy back the symlinks to where they came from.